# Remove if statement and make it more readable

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Hi wondering if there is a better way to remove this else if statement and use a strategy pattern.
any ideas?

```
public async Task<TResponse> HandleResponseAsync<TRequest, TResponse>(TRequest item)
    where TResponse : class, new()
{
    TResponse result = default(TResponse);
    Type currentResponseType = typeof(TResponse);   

    if (currentResponseType == typeof(MyResponseA))
    {
        result = //dosomething
    }
    else if (currentResponseType == typeof(MyResponseB))
    { 
        result = //dosomething
    }
    else if (currentResponseType == typeof(MyResponseC))
    {
        result = //dosomething
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: What's `itemType`? Note that this question would probably be better on codereview. Personally I'd use a nested conditional operator... or at the very least remove the pointless `result` variable and just return as soon as you know the value you want to return.

Comment: You have already suggested the best idea

Comment: itemtype was a typo corrected

Comment: You could implement your "dosomething" as a method on TResponse, probably best implemented on an interface that all TResponse types could derive from. Then you simply call result.DoSomething() instead of testing for the individual types. Obviously, you would need to pass any contextual information into your DoSomething method.

Comment: this is already a good way to do it. If you want to simplify the statement you can do return currentResponseType == typeof(MyResponseA) ? xxx: currentResponseType == typeof(MyResponseB) : yyy : currentResponseType == typeof(MyResponseC): zzz : default(TResponse); or use a switch statement

Comment: @MoonMoo: Though that is in general good advice, in this case the premise of the question is that we don't have an instance of the response object in hand; rather, we're attempting to get one. (Though the fact that `TResponse` has the `new` constraint is perhaps evidence that the caller *could* have obtained one.)

Comment: @EricLippert That's true, though you could still have a method on a class that knows how to create instances of itself. Admittedly, It's not a clean implementation and a factory would be better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using specific subclasses inside a generic method is a very dangerous approach, because it limits future flexibility by locking you up into the list of classes inside the generic method. It also throws away most of the advantages that you could get from making it a generic method.

Since you already require a no-argument constructor, one approach is to give your `TResponse` an interface, and use that interface to call back into the instance to make proper result:

```
interface IResponse {
    void Configure(); // Use custom parameters if necessary
}

public async Task<TResponse> HandleResponseAsync<TRequest, TResponse>(TRequest item)  where TResponse : class, new(), IResponse {
    TResponse result = new TResponse();
    result.Configure(...);
}
```

Now the code from if-then-else blocks would go into `Configure` methods of the corresponding `IResponse` implementations:

```
class MyResponseA : IResponse {
    public MyResponseA() {}
    public void Configure() {
        // dosomething from the first IF
    }
}
class MyResponseB : IResponse {
    public MyResponseB() {}
    public void Configure() {
        // dosomething from the second IF
    }
}
```

**Note:** Things may get tricky if different instances require different information from the `HandleResponseAsync` to be passed to them. In this case you should also create an object that holds all information that any of the implementations may need in order to complete its `Configure` method.

Comment: Yep, this is what I was trying to explain ;)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight  could you expand your answer with a noddy sample just to be clear ,it looks/sounds good

Comment: @MoonMoo Given the limits of a comment, you explained it quite accurately, too :-)

Answer (score 5):

If you're switching on the type of a generic, you're probably doing something wrong. Generics should be **generic**. The code you've written is not generic, it's *extremely fragile*, and generics make it more, not less complicated.

Here, let me rewrite that for you:

```
if (currentResponseType == typeof(MyResponseA))
    return (TResponse) HandleResponseA(item);
else if (currentResponseType == typeof(MyResponseB))
    return (TResponse) HandleResponseB(item);
else if (currentResponseType == typeof(MyResponseC))
    return (TResponse) HandleResponseC(item);
```

If there are three possible code paths through the method, no more, no less, then simply write three methods `HandleResponseA`, `HandleResponseB`, `HandleResponseC`. **That's what you did already anyways**, you just put the body of each of those methods as the body of an `if`.  There's no *savings* here in making them all one method; you've just made a fragile, over-complicated method.  Now that we've refactored your method, **we see that we can delete the method entirely and simply call the appropriate handler directly**.

Also, consider your poor callers! At the call site there's no compelling reason to prefer `HandleResponseAsync<Giraffe, MyResponseB>(giraffe)` to the much better `HandleResponseB(giraffe)`; the call site is shorter, clearer, and safer if there are three methods instead of one.

Moreover, if the service provided here depends 100% on the type of the response object, then **why isn't this a concern of the response object**?  Why isn't the call site actually `MyResponseB.Handle(giraffe)`? The methods could be static methods of the response type. If you're going to write three method bodies, one for each type, then **put them on that type**.

Comment: Yes, [Overengineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overengineering) is the catchword. Often people want to do dynamic stuff with generics. Generics are doubtfully great but not dynamic.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: Right; the original code is an abstraction that is *more* complicated, dangerous and hard to use than the things being abstracted!  Just delete the abstraction; it's getting in the way.

Answer (score 1):

in **c# 7** you can use `switch`

```
       var response = new TRsponse();
        switch (response)
        {
            case MYResponseB b:
                break;

            case MYResponse a:
                break;

         }
```

> We’re generalizing the switch statement so that: 1. You can switch on any type (not just primitive types) 2.Patterns can be used in case clauses 3.Case clauses can have additional conditions on them

here are new features in c# 7:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/

Comment: This isn't very extensible though. If you look at @dasblinkenlight's implementation, there is never a need to change the HandleResponseAsync method should more TReponse types be required.

Comment: Switch statements and if-else chains are often an indication that the code is more procedural than object-oriented. The solution is to use [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) and let the objects themselves do what has to be done. See @dasblinkenlight's answer.

Comment: I agree with you guys, this is just a new feature, not an elegant design pattern @MoonMoo

Comment: This is a great feature when working with APIs that yield weakly typed values as in `myDataTable.Rows[i][j]` where the type of a column may vary. It will become even more useful in C#8.0 when recursive pattern matching will become available.

Comment: Great answers guys, I am working with some code that I can change up to a point whether is good or bad. I will think about it and  post a reply and accept accordingly.many thanks